# Determine cause of low bandwidth on solid Ethernet cable with stranded connectors

Tags: ethernet, cable, rj-45, cat5e

I installed stranded RJ-45 modular plugs on solid Cat5e cable. My cable tester shows all cables are OK, but all except one won't go beyond 100 Mbps (I have a 300/300 connection).

How can I determine why my cables don't support more bandwidth? Are the plugs a plausible explanation of this?

Comment: Cat5e and not more than 10 m

Comment: `(except one cable)`- What does that cable do? What speeds are the cables rated for? 1gbps? 300mbps? 10mbps?

Comment: Also Cat5e solid, and also with connector plugs for Cat5e stranded but for some reason the actual speed is 1000Mbps. Cannot explain why. But the rest of the cables I put togeter will only do 100Mbps

Comment: Are you using the cable tester to determine the cables' max bandwidth, or another method?

Comment: I used the tester just to determine if we had wired the plugs correctly, i.e. matching sequence of lights (1-8) on the tester and the remote. That part was OK, but once I plugged the cables into the switch only one cable negotiated to 1000Mbps whereas the rest only negotiates to 100Mbps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most certainly due to using the wrong type of modular connectors. As shown below, the contacts in RJ-45 plugs made for stranded wire "pierce" the cable, whereas in solid wire plugs they "straddle" the cable:

[image]
[Source](http://www.l-com.com/multimedia/tips/tip_stranded_vs_solid.pdf)

A stranded plug used with solid cable will not make a good connection. The connector will attempt to pierce the solid wire, but will either simply "press" into it or split it into smaller pieces. Neither of these scenarios will result in a solid connection that can resist the normal physical movement associated with patch cable installation and use.

You should install the correct type of connectors for your cable type.

Comment: Good explanation and fine illustration.